# Import Wizard Error

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, bulkinsert

I'm hoping someone can help with a mystifying error.

I have run a query in SQL Server, saved the results as a `.csv`, and then turned around and tried to import the `.csv` back into another database in SQL Server and create a table from it using the import wizard.

But when I do that, I get the error messages below:

```
Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "ACCOUNT_NM" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "output column "ACCOUNT_NM" (22)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "ACCOUNT_NM" (22)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing file "D:\Documents\James Project\Main Table\outer_query_new.csv" on data row 69.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - outer_query_new_csv" (1) returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

I've tried going to `Advanced` in the `Data Source` dialog box and changing the `ACCOUNT_NM` to `OutputColumnWidth 70` or `90` or `255`, with no luck.

Also going to `Advanced` in the `Data Source` dialog box and changing the `ACCOUNT_NM` data type to `DT_TEXT` or `DT_NTEXT`, with no luck.

I've tried going to the `Edit Mappings` dialog box and changing the the `Destination Type` for `ACCOUNT_NM` to `NVARCHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, `VARCHAR(MAX)`, and `TEXT` with still no luck.

I've also tried a simple `BULK INSERT` statement with `FIELDTERMINATOR=';', ROWTERMINATOR='/n'`, which gives the errors below:

```
Msg 4866, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: What do you get if you change the `/n` in your `ROWTERMINATOR` parameter to `\n`?

Comment: I think it might not be an issue with the length of the column but the second part of the message. "or one or more characters had no match in the target code page." Whats the datatype of ACCOUNT_NM in the table that you create the CSV from?

Comment: Also you could open your CSV file and go to data row 69 and check if Account_NM column has any weird characters.

Comment: at first place when you created csv file from query result, what was the data type for field ACCOUNT_NM. you have checked both source and destination mapping since truncation can happens at both end.

Comment: in one of the error messages it says "on data row 69" have you tried checking that row to see what is in it that could be failing

Comment: Also as @TMNT2014 suggested, trying setting code page to UTF-8 in your wizard.

Answer (score 1):

I solved Error 0xc02020a1 by enlarging the lenght of the columns with the error (the ones that hold descriptions in my case), From varchar(50) to varchar(100).

Greetings